# Adding items to a new array using an array method

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Having difficulties with data testing and cannot get my function to return the new array in full (it stops at the first item).

Here's the object that my function is testing:

```
it("should list out all of the order items by name", function() {
      var order1 = {
        orderNumber: 1,
        item: "burger",
        price: "8.99",
        orderType: "delivery",
        status: "accepted"
      };

      var order2 = {
        orderNumber: 2,
        item: "blt sandwich",
        price: "5.99",
        orderType: "delivery",
        status: "accepted"
      };

      var order3 = {
        orderNumber: 3,
        item: "rueben",
        price: "8.99",
        orderType: "delivery",
        status: "accepted"
      };

      var deliveryOrders = [order1, order2, order3];
      var items = listItems(deliveryOrders);

      assert.deepEqual(items, "burger, blt sandwich, rueben");
    });
```

This is my function. I think I need a different array method to return the new array (using 'concat' at the moment).

This is the error message that my terminal is returning:

1. order.js 
   listOrders 
   should list out all of the order items by name: 
   AssertionError: expected 1 to deeply equal 'burger, blt     sandwich, rueben'

```
function listItems(deliveryOrders) {
  var itemList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < deliveryOrders.length; i++) {
    return itemList.push(deliveryOrders[i].item);
  }
 itemList.concat(deliveryOrders[i].item);
}
```

Comment: I think you mistakenly posted the test code twice...

Comment: Why are you returning inside the for loop?

Comment: ty, popping that outside of the loop and testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a simple error with the function listItems,You are pushing to the object to your array and returning it,once the function performs the first push,it returns.So the next iterations in the for loop do not take place.
What you can do is
-for each iteration in the loop,push the object to the array.
-once all the objects are pushed to the array the loop will stop execution
-now you have an array that contains all the objects
-simple return the array from the function.

```
let itemList =[];
function listItems(deliveryOrders){
for(let i=0;i<deliveryOrders.length;i++){
itemList.push(deliveryOrders[i].item);
}
return itemList;
}
```

Try the code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning function listItems after first iteration of the for loop, instead it should be:

```
function listItems(deliveryOrders) {
  var itemList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < deliveryOrders.length; i++) {
    itemList.push(deliveryOrders[i].item);
  }
 return itemList;
}
```